# explanations of the algorithm of decoding polylines from google directions api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I have been searching for a method to decode Google Directions popylines for a while.
This function worked for me but the problem is that I don't understand the code. There is no article in [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com) about decoding polyline of Google directions.

```
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
      int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
      do {
        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
      } while (b >= 0x20);
      int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
      lat += dlat;

      shift = 0;
      result = 0;
      do {
        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
        shift += 5;
      } while (b >= 0x20);
      int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
      lng += dlng;

      LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
          (((double) lng / 1E5)));
      poly.add(p);
    }
    return poly;
  }
}
```

Comment: the google maps utility library can do this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/

Comment: this library is supported in API 8 and above! and i'm using min api 7

Comment: So go and pull just the code that decrypts the polyline

Comment: besides if you are using google maps how are you using API 7? google play service works with API 8 and up at the very minimum

Comment: i'm using android support library.

Comment: the function i've posted is working fine.. I just want to understand the algorithm of decoding polylines

Comment: all you have to do it look at the link and it explains how polylines are encoded https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm